# Is it possible to use common resource bundles for several reports?

Tags: internationalization, jasper-reports

I have created a jasper report with 3 resource bundles to cater to internationalization. The name of the report is, let's say, 'testreport' and the bundle names are 'testreport_pt_BR.properties', 'testreport_en_US.properties' and 'testreport_fr_FR.properties'.

Now, if I have 10 reports should I create 3 resource bundles for every report? Or can I create one and use it in all of them?

I ask this because I remember reading the name of the report and the resource bundles must be the same

Comment: `Now, if I have 10 reports should I create 3 resource bundles for every report? Or can I create one and use it in all of them?` - You can use the same properties file or you can use different files, as you wish

Comment: Then my understanding of 'name of the report and the resource bundles must be the same' must be incorrect, right?

Comment: The name can be any. `I ask this because I remember reading the name of the report and the resource bundles must be the same` - This is wrong assumption